# MongoDB group by (+ sort & limit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

So I have the following group by SQL

```
select count(*) as NO_OF_MSGS,FROM_USER,PROFILE_IMG,MSG from MESSAGES group by FROM_USER order by NO_OF_MSGS desc,DATE_SENT limit ?,?
```

How can I replicate this group by in MongoDB. I came across this excellent write up - http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/11/mongodb-count-group/

This shows how you can use group by in Mongo, but it **does not** talk about how to implement `order by` and `limit` inside a group.

Also it seems Mongoid does not provide support for `group` function, anyone know if its any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I replicate this group by in MongoDB. I came across this excellent write up - http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/11/mongodb-count-group/

First off, that is a 2-year old write-up. Those operators (`count`, `group`, `distinct`) are still functional but they are quite slow. Using any of those operators amounts to running a Map/Reduce. And I'm not sure that sharding was ever implemented for those operators (*note that the blog post pre-dates sharding*).

The modern way to do this would be to use the new [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework). This is both much faster and supports sharding. However, it is still in the unstable build.

> This shows how you can use group by in Mongo, but it does not talk about how to implement order by and limit inside a group.

The query you are converting is a simple query in SQL, but this is not a simple query in MongoDB. The problem you are likely having with Mongoid is simply that you are doing something that MongoDB simply does not support (*outside of the new Aggregation Framework*).

If you do not have access to the Aggregation Framework, you will need to do this in multiple steps.

1. Run a M/R to get the `count(*) grouped by X`.
2. Do a query on the M/R output with your `sort()`, `skip()`, `limit()`.
3. The above may not work if you have too much data to sort (~1M users), you may need to index the output of the M/R for the sort to work.

Comment: Very good answer. Here is a related question with a similar answer and some example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508826/how-to-query-group-by-and-distinct-with-a-limit-in-mongodb-php-codeigniter/20395865

Answer (score 2):

For grouping you can use group_by method of rails

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

And for ordering you can use sort_by method of Array

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Mongoid: Querying](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html).

It provides an explanation of how to use `order_by` and `limit`.

EDIT:

Removed comment about `distinct` and `group by` being equivalent as @mu pointed out. Instead, you should use `group` and provide a reduce function as detailed in the article you linked to.

Comment: Um, "distinct" and "group by" are very different when aggregate functions (such as `count`) are involved.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was sloppy. I fixed my answer.