# how to query group by and distinct with a limit in MongoDB PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

Is such a operation possible?

sample record:

```
{ 
 _id: ObjectId("51d6be147483c58419000002"), 
 user: "ashok", 
 action: "login",
 time: 1373027860,
 details: { 
               user_entries:   "blah..blah", 
               url: "web.domain.com" 
                 }
 }
```

Suppose, i want to group by url visited, for each user,
group by url where user = "ashok", limit 10.

I am using [AlexBilbie](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2) library for MongoDB-Codeigniter (it doesnt have aggregation). so using plain php.
Still even if I could aggregate, how to distinct or limit it?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I'm a littlebit unsure what you want the end result document to look like.. could you post an example of how it should look like? I am assuming each user could have visited the same url multiple times.. Do you want to count how many times he has visited each url?

Comment: suppose if users "ashok" & "bob" visits the page welcome.html 10 times and 20 times respectively, i would like a result like, ashok: 10 and bob:20 grouped by url visited and distinct by user.(i also want to limit the result but that's fine for now)

Answer (score 2):

First of all using group_by and distinct together doesn't make any sense. Either you are using group_by or distinct.

If you want to do some kind of pagination for a grouped query you have to use map and reduce or the aggregation pipeline. In your case the aggregation would look like that.

```
db.users.aggregate(
  { '$match' => { 'user' => 'ashok' } },
  { '$group' => { '_id' => '$details.url' } },
  { '$skip'  => 0 },
  { '$limit' => 10 }
)
```

I am using this aggregation feature to display [references at VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/php/symfony%3asymfony/references). The aggregation feature allows to do grouping and paging on db level, that's why it's much faster then other ORM or pagination solutions.

Comment: Thanks but, suppose i have 2 users, A & B. A visits 1.html two times, 2.html five times; B visits 1.html three times, 2.html six times. Will this work? to have results like A saw 1.html 2 times...etc?

Comment: No. The aggregation pipeline doesn't count values like that. In your case you have to use map and reduce.

Answer (score 0):

In the below format you can give a limit:

```
$this->mongo_db->order_by(array('Student_Name'=>'asc'))->limit(20)->get('mycollection_name');
```